# Jquery Background Animate

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use the background animate method in JQuery but it just doesn't work. Here's the code I am using for it.

```
$(".menu_item").mouseenter(function(){$(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FF8040"}, 'fast');});
$(".menu_item").mouseleave(function(){$(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#999"}, 'fast');});
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

---

Heres the rest of it.

The Html for the menu:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="index.html" id="home_menu" class="menu_item">Home</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="menu_item">Tutorials</a>
    <a href="index.html" class="menu_item">News</a>
</div>
```

and the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery().ready(function(){
            $(".menu_item").mouseenter(function(){$(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FF8040"}, 'fast');});
            $(".menu_item").mouseleave(function(){$(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#999"}, 'fast');});

            var pos = $("#fixed_head").position();
            var height = $("#fixed_head").height();
            var height2 = $("#menu").height();

            var screenHeight = $("body").height();
            var newHeight = screenHeight - height - height2;
            $("#container").css("top", (pos.top + height));
            $("#container").css("height", newHeight);
            $("#content").css("height", newHeight);

            $(window).resize(function() {
                var pos = $("#fixed_head").position();
                var height = $("#fixed_head").height();
                var height2 = $("#menu").height();

                var screenHeight = $("body").height();
                var newHeight = screenHeight - height - height2;
                $("#container").css("top", (pos.top + height));
                $("#container").css("height", newHeight);
                $("#content").css("height", newHeight);
            });

        });

    });
    </script>
```

and in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please show sample HTML.

Comment: Pay attention, there is no need in nested 'DOM ready' handlers. Use first only.

Comment: Yeah I figured that, just didn't remove it. But it doesn't appear to make a difference to this. Do I need a extra Jquery file for UI?

Comment: Yes, you can download it from here: http://jqueryui.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library your code should work. It has color transition effects for [`animate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) method.

Another way to write it is:

```
$(".menu_item").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FF8040"
    }, 'fast');
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "#999"
    }, 'fast');
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kbKdY/

Comment: Yeah I thought that might have been it, hadn't used anything from that library before so I didn't know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `jQuery UI 1.8.18` file in the head section.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not direct answer to your question, but why don't you use CSS transitions?

Still, you can use jQuery to add/remove class on mouse events.

CSS transitions are fast (faster than JS animations) and quite reliable. If the browser doesn't support css transitions the background colour will change (but there will be no animation/transition) - it's a win/win situation.

**Sample code here: http://jsfiddle.net/GuSQx/**